# Datepicker won't function inside colorbox

Tags: php, jquery, colorbox, uidatepicker

Here the scenario:
I want to apply a datepicker on a input field in a form.
When clicking a link a colorbox will open containing the form.

Somehow the datepicker doesn't work, so I searched the internet.
I was confused by this post [datepicker inside a thickbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809391/jquery-ui-datepicker-inside-a-thickbox) where the following statement was made:
**JavaScript/jQuery is not working inside of ColorBox.**
It confused me because other people seem to have worked it out.

I'll show the code of the colorbox call:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".customer").colorbox(
                {
                  transition:'fade',
                    width:'750',
                    speed:'500',
                    height:'400',
                    iframe:true
                });
        });
        </script>
```

The colorbox opens successfully although my error console says there is a } missing after the first }); occurrence.

The code for the datepicker:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datepick').datepicker({
    changeYear:true,
    yearRange:'c-65:c+0',
    changeMonth:true
    });
    $('.datepick').datepicker($.datepicker.regional['nl']);});</script>
```

This code does work somewhere else on my website where it is not located in a colorbox.

What I have tried:

1. I tried to give the class datepick a z-index of 10000 or higher since colorbox has a z-index of 9999 by default.
2. I tried the oncomplete function() on the colorbox, but couldn't get the colorbox work when applied.
3. I tried setting iframe to false in combination with the previous two options.

My question(s):

1. Is it possible to have a datepicker working inside a colorbox?
2. Is my code about the colorbox correct?
3. How to fix it?!

**UPDATE**
Solution: I made a stupid mistake :P...
Yet I found the answers on my first question, which may be of some value.

1. Yes it is possible to have a datepicker working inside a colorbox without using the onComplete:function().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your loaded iframe contain the datepicker instantiation code?

My assumption is this:

- you have an anchor with a `class="customer"`
- this anchor has an href, which points the the page you want to show in the colorbox
- this page loads in an iframe (due to `iframe:true`)
- and this page doesn't have your datepicker instantiation code

The easiest thing to do is to move the datepicker code to the onready function of the `customer` page.

Comment: The datepicker function is located in the loaded page. The anchor which opens the colorbox is: <a class="customer" href="customer.php">add customer</a>. If I understand you correctly I have already done what you suggest. Correct me if I didn't.

Comment: So, what happens when you go directly to customer.php?  Does the datepicker work? If not, what error do you see?

Comment: Thank you very much for that hint! :) I noticed an error in the page just before datepicker was going to be loaded. That solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

As noted in [ColorBox documentation](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/#timing):

> *This is often due to trying to access an element before it has been loaded into the document and can be resolved by moving the JavaScript into ColorBox's onComplete callback.*

Example (using jQuery Forms plugin):

```
$('#login_window').colorbox({
    ...
    onComplete:function(){
        $('form#login').ajaxForm();
}});
```

You can adapt the example to load the datepicker.

Comment: As I said I tried the onComplete:function(). And isn't it the same as $(document).ready(function())? Got my datepicker in the colorbox working now without the onComplete:function(). Thanks anyway for the help :).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. 
I used an id as selector, but colorbox duplicate the whole html content and the id's too. 
So if I use $('#myid').doSomething() I got an error, because "myid" was duplicated. 
Thats the issus.

Use a better selector like $('#colorbox .myidasclass').doSomething() to solve the issue. 
The same problem is with class selector without the '#colorbox' as additional selector.